# Develop the openstack manage website like the original dashboard

Tags: openstack

I installed the HA OpenStack on 3 host machines, and them works perfect.

As you know, the HA OpenStack has a original dashboard, I can access from browser: `http://44.118.44.1xx/dashboard`, now I want to write a new website to do the dashboard's functions.

and I want to develop the site on my Mac, how to do with that?

I don't know how to connect with the original HA openstack's database(there are mariadb cluster).
because in the website, I will register the user(tenant), I will put the tenant information to the mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

In Openstack you are not advised to connect to DB directly. Each services in Openstack exposes API(primarily it shall be REST API). Assuming you are trying to build website from scratch, you can use javascript or similar to call REST APIs. [here is quick start guide for using REST APIs](https://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/quick-start/api-quick-start.html). You can fine complete list of services and its REST APIs description [Here](https://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/quick-start/).

Comment: how can i develop the site on my mac.but the openstack is on remote server.  the rest api is on server.alright?

Comment: Yes, you need to call REST API's on server. from the website you are using javascript. If you do not want to waste time in recreating what Horizon does, you can very wel install Openstack cli in you mac. and use cli.

Comment: I want to create a website like dashboard, and it can realize the dashboard's functions. and the user have many other info, such as email, telphone, if I start the project, i should install the openstack on a server, but I am develop in my mac, when register the user, it will input like email and telphone， it should store in the database(the openstack database, alright?). so , in my mac I develop the project, how can I connect my project to the database(openstack using).